# ignore recursive, including dynamically generateed files and directories

Tags: svn, svnignore

Just as the title explains - is it possible to set an ignore property on a directory recursively, including dynamically generated files and directories.

For example, I have a tmp folder which will constantly get a lot of other files and folders added to and removed from.

Comment: What have you tried? What does the directory layout look like? Where are the generated files saved, is there a common pattern to the naming?

Comment: Thanks nachito - i have been using svn:propset with an ignore file containing the top level directories.  For example tmp/media tmp/css tmp/js.  The problem is when new directories get added dynamically after the propset then they are not automatically ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no versioned files in tmp then I would svn:ignore that directory at the top level. Otherwise you'll have to find a pattern that matches the generated files and not the versioned files (e.g. force generated files to be named **generated-FOO.bar** and svn:ignore that pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Look into

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ...
```

While it is best to avoid having to do recursive things (by ignoring entire generated directories), if you want to force a file system branch to ignore items recurisvely, then use

```
svn -R propset svn:ignore ignorefile.txt ...
```

Which comes with the caveat that you will override the ignored patterns that might be set below with your new set of ignored patterns.

Comment: Hi Edwin - i am using your second method the propset with a file containing my patterns.  However, when new directories are added they are not automatically ignored and begin to pollute the repo

Comment: Drew, why are you adding temporary directories to SVN?  You don't want to store a history of generated items, you want to store the framework to generate them again in the future.  Otherwise, you'll wind up with two authoritative sources for one end of build item (a very bad idea).

Comment: Im am not adding them to the repository.  I have a dev site and a production site.  The framework I am using automatically generates these temporary folders.  When working on my dev site i then have to be careful with commits not to add these temporary folders so when i update my production site these changes dont get brought in.  I want to ignore everything that sits under the temp folder to make committing and updating a bit easier

Comment: Then svn ignore everything under the tmp directory.  svn:ignore works for files and directories equally well.

Comment: Or, svn:ignore the tmp directory, and have it created by the "build system" you use (ant, make, cmake, automake, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to setup global ignore rule in svn config file:

```
global-ignores = tmp
```

But, you should remember that it will be activated for newly created working dirs, this possibly will ignore what you were not intended (use some rare and specific name) and will not be stored in SVN repo (as property).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your context, you might also look into the "global-ignores" configuration field in ~/.subversion/config.  It's defined on a per-user basis, not stored as part of the repository.

http://borkware.com/quickies/single?id=260